# Drawing outside canvas on an other view

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

In in my xml-layout I have a View as im drawing an icon tracking my finger.

The other half of the screen is a simple LinearLayout.
Im wondering if im able to draw outside my view and draw above/on the linearlayout?

I have tried to clip the canvas of my view with this code:

```
 Rect newRect = canvas.getClipBounds();
 newRect.inset(0,400);
 canvas.clipRect(newRect, Op.REPLACE); 

 canvas.drawBitmap(icon,fingerTouchX,fingerTouchY,null);
```

and i've also added `android:clipChildren="false"` in the xml layout for the linearLayout.
I have turned off hardware acceleration.

Though, it's not working. Does anyone know if this is possible to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe creation new instance of `Paint` instead of **null** works for you?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only *draw* on the view you are in since the canvas dimensions don't extend to outside that view. You could have the `View` you are drawing on, be over the other view (in your case the `LinearLayout`) so that it draw on the area of the other view even if it's not on the view itself.

[image]

So in short, you **can't** draw on another view while painting one view's canvas, but you can convey the effect of painting on that other view if the area of the first one contains that of the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You need call inset with negative value:

```
newRect.inset(0, -400);
```